# How to sign a get request from a link_to button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, api-auth

I am using `api_auth` to sign my requests. I have a link_to button that makes a get request to a controller (allowing my admins to sign in as any users via `Devise`).

```
link_to "Click Here", "https://localhost:3000/sign_in_as_user?admin_user=#{current_user.id}&user_id=#{s.id}", target: "_blank"
```

I've read through the `api_auth` doc (https://github.com/mgomes/api_auth) and see how I can generate a signed request in controllers.

However, I want to be able to create a signed_request when I click on the above `link_to` tag.

**How do I successfully sign a link_to get request?**

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a helper method, or controller method that creates the signed request.  Then you can link to the action that creates the signed request for you.

```
link_to "Click Here", {:action => :new_action_to_create_signed_request}, :method => :post
```